# Disable intellij "unnecessary boxing" for hex and octal int literals

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij flags code like:

```
float f = Float.valueOf(0x123);
float g = Float.valueOf(0123);
double h = Double.valueOf(0123);
System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", f, g, h);
```

as using unnecessary boxing. It suggests fixing it to:

```
float f = 0x123f;
float g = 0123f;
double h = 0123d;
System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", f, g, h);
```

which isn't the same. Whereas the first code prints:

```
291.0 83.0 83.0
```

the second code prints:

```
4671.0 123.0 123.0
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/VrF2CW)

because the `f` on `0x123f` is considered a hex digit, and the leading `0` on `0123f` and `0123d` doesn't cause floating point numbers to be considered in octal.

Is there any way to disable this inspection *just* for hex and octal literals, or would you just have to disable the whole inspection?

Comment: Have you filed a bug-report yet? That is broken. Right now you are "only" looking for a work-around, right?

Comment: Just filed this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186852. Yes, I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just assign it directly (`float f = 0x123;`) or cast it (`(float)0x123;`)? It does seem unnecessary to bring `Float` into a direct primitive conversion, even if the suggested fix is a bug.

Comment: @Dukeling it's merely a minimal example. It's obviously unnecessary, and the inspection is correct to flag it; however, the fix is wrong, and this is bad if you want to apply the fix across your whole project.

Comment: (not that converting an octal int literal to a wrapped float is a particularly common thing to do... but that makes it worse, in a way, because you're not going to spot it in amongst other unnecessary boxings which are less weird).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to disable this inspection just for hex and octal literals. You can suppress the inspection for specific occurrences of such literals in your code by pressing the right arrow in the Alt-Enter menu and selecting the desired suppress option.